# ::before/::after + flexbox in MDN

Tags: css

I see the following news item on [MDN CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) homepage:

> Gecko's support of flexible boxes has been adapted to match a recent specification clarification: from Firefox 23 `::before` and `::after` will be flex items, and as such can be repositioned using `order` and `align-self`.
>   (May 3rd, 2013)

What specification does it refer to?
I cannot find any references to `::before`/`::after` in [CSS Flexible Box Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-flexbox-20120918/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was implemented in [bug 867454](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=867454). Not implementing it was a mistake, as comment #0 tells.

The [spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/#flex-items) says:

> The contents of a flex container consists of zero or more flex items: each in-flow child of a flex container becomes a flex item, and each contiguous run of text that is directly contained inside a flex container is wrapped in an anonymous flex item.

And that does include `::before`/`::after` pseudo elements (at least the mozilla folks interpret it this way now, and I'd concur).

["Firefox 23 for developers"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/23) also features this information, explicitly referring to `::before` and `::after` as "in-flow".

> In-flow ::after and ::before pseudo-elements are now flex items (bug 867454).

Comment: I wanted to clarify the spec as I'm using this technique in a project. I can confirm it's correct and works well in IE10+, Edge, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Is there a way to make it not a flex item?